# Primefaces hotkey selector

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm migrating from Richfaces to Primefaces. In Richfaces hotkey use:

```
<rich:hotKey key="return" selector="#firstNameTxtField"
handler="#{rich:element('saveButton')}.click();event.stopPropagation(); 
event.preventDefault();return false;"/>
```

What attribute can replace the `selector` in Primefaces?

Answer (score 1):

In Primefaces hotkey is not able to use a selector. 
Maybe DefaultAction (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml) helps you in this case.